# Pass label string data to UIPickerView

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am not familiar with `UIPickerView`. Now I have two Controllers, let's say Controller A & Controller B.
Controller A has a label called "apple", and Controller B has a `UIPickerView` with data of ["banana","watermelon","strawberry"].

The question is, if I need to pass "apple" from Controller A to Controller B and show on `UIPickerView`, what should I do?

I tried to use titleForRow function in Controller B like below.

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    fruitData[row] = self.data.name ?? ""
    return fruitData[row]
}
```

data.name is "apple" as I mentioned earlier.
After I complied, title for pickerView showed three "apple". Apparently, this is not what I was looking for. I need "apple" show, but also need to keep array data of ["banana","watermelon","strawberry"]. As I would like to change value of `UIPickerView` back to Controller A, I have to keep array data otherwise I only have "apple" as choice.

Can someone help me out with this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, **append** the "apple" to your data source and then reload the picker.

```
fruitData.append(data.name)
yourPickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

If you want to **insert** the apple in a particular position, use the insert instead of append.

```
fruitData.insert("apple", at: 0)
```

Or something better would be to *insert* the fruit into the **correct position**. Seeing that yours in ascending order.

```
if let index = fruitData.firstIndex(where: { data.name < $0 }) {
    fruitData.insert(data.name, at: index)
} else {
    fruitData.append(data.name)
}
```